# Can this data model be nested?

Tags: swiftui, nested, datamodel

Can this data model be nested, I've tried
many things, and I can't get it to work.

```
struct Response: Codable {
   struct Result: Codable {
       var trackId: Int
       var trackName: String
       var collectionName: String
   }
    var results: [Result]
}
```

This doesn't work, is there a way?

For reference:
This example is from a Paul Hudson
video tutorial.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}
struct Result: Codable {
    var trackId: Int
    var trackName: String
    var collectionName: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var results = [Result]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(results, id: \.trackId) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.trackName)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text(item.collectionName)
                        .font(.caption)
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await loadData()
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song&limit=4") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                results = decodedResponse.results
            }
        } catch {
            print("Invalid Data")
        }
    }
}
```

I can't think of any more details.  I just
dont understand this, at this point.

Comment: Yes it can. In `ContentView`, use `@State private var results = [Response.Result]()` and it will work. Read the basics of Swift again.

Comment: never use `try?` and change `print("Invalid Data")` to `print("Invalid Data \(error)")`

Comment: Paul Hudson's SwiftUI code looks to have seriously improved since I last checked, could you share the link to the tutorial? Thanks

Comment: The PH example is from Cupcake Corner SwiftUI Tutorial 1/9.  There is an older version which used the request, data, error URLSession, and this async await updated version.

Answer (score 0):

As workingdog said, you can nest the types, but your property must reflect the fully qualified type name, now `Response.Result`:

```swift
@State private var results = [Response.Result]()
```

---

Unrelated, but I would also advise:

1. Avoid `try?` (because if it failed, you will silently ignore the problem);
2. Prefer `let` over `var` in the properties of your object wherever possible, as it is always easier to reason about immutable objects than mutable ones … only use `var` where you need mutable properties; and
3. If you have an error, don't just print “Invalid data” but include the actual error.

E.g.

```swift
struct Response: Codable {
    let results: [Result]                             // use `let` instead of `var`, unless you really need mutability
    
    struct Result: Codable {
        let trackId: Int
        let trackName: String
        let collectionName: String
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var results = [Response.Result]()  // `Response.Result`
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(results, id: \.trackId) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.trackName)
                        .font(.headline)
                    Text(item.collectionName)
                        .font(.caption)
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await loadData()
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song&limit=4") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }

        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            results = try JSONDecoder()              // use `try`, not `try?`
                .decode(Response.self, from: data)
                .results   
        } catch {
            print("Invalid Data", error)             // include the error, so if it failed, you can meaningfully diagnose what went wrong
        }
    }
}
```

There are lots of other potential refinements (e.g., if there was an error, show something user-friendly in the UI, etc.), but that is probably beyond the scope of this question.

---

As a final observation, while you *can* embed the nested type inside the `Response` object, it begs the question as to whether you *should.* These are two different types of things. `Response` is an API structure. The type of the `results` array is a model type (a “track”, an “album”, etc.). I would not advise entangling these together.

E.g., this API follows a consistent convention of `{"results":[…]}`, where the types of the objects inside that array will vary depending upon the `entity` parameter of the request.

So that begs for *not* embedding the subtypes inside `Response`. Personally, I would use a generic pattern:

```swift
struct Track: Codable {
    let trackId: Int
    let trackName: String
    let collectionName: String
}

struct Album: Codable {
    let albumId: Int
    let albumName: String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case albumId = "collectionId"
        case albumName = "collectionName"
    }
}

struct Response<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let results: T
}
```

So the function that requests albums can parse a `Response<Track>`, but the endpoint that fetches albums can parse a `Response<Album>`. Etc.

IMHO, these model objects (`Track`, `Album`, etc.) do not belong inside `Response` type.

Then you can do things like:

```swift
@State private var tracks = [Track]()

func loadData() async {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=taylor+swift&entity=song&limit=4") else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }

    do {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        tracks = try JSONDecoder()
            .decode(Response.self, from: data)   // it infers the generic for us
            .results
    } catch {
        print("Invalid Data", error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am loving the refinement to the do-catch, try-.decode stuff.  Very! helpful for me.  I tried to use Response.Result in the .decode before, and that didn't work.  Response.self finds the Result struct in the .decode, but it doesn't work the other direction.  I'm a beginner.middle, and I got stuck.  Wow-the comments are very helpful.

Comment: Yeah, the `Response.Result` is only in the declaration of the `var results = [Response.Result]()`,  but the `decode` is still `Response.self`, as shown in first snippet above.